# Error while building java dd4t2.0 with message "Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-gpg-plugin:1.5:sign (sign-artifacts)"

Tags: dd4t, java

**i am trying to do POC with dd4t 2.0 latest version and facing build error.**

Please help me to resolve this maven dependency, i am getting error while building this project

> [INFO] --- maven-gpg-plugin:1.5:sign (sign-artifacts) @
> dd4t-spring-mvc-archetype --- 'gpg.exe' is not recognized as an
> internal or external command,
>
> Failed to execute goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-gpg-plugin:1.5:sign (sign-artifacts) on
> project dd4t-spring-mvc-archetype: Exit code: 1

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>sign</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting this error is because you're trying to build with the **release-central** profile in Maven. You are not allowed to do this, you can remove the profile from your build configuration.

So if you have something like:

```
mvn clean install -Prelease-central
```

.. then that won't work.

In general, you should just load the dd4t dependencies as real dependencies and *not* as source code. This will make things a lot easier and clear. Please see the [quickstart guide](https://github.com/dd4t/dd4t-2-java) and the [wiki](https://github.com/dd4t/dd4t-2-java/wiki) for more information.

**Update**

From the comments I see that you are loading in the archetype as module. This is also not possible. What you get then is the source to generate an archetype package, which then generates a base project based on parameters. If you want to use the archetype, the only way to do that is by doing:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=[com.example] -DartifactId=[mywebapp] -DarchetypeGroupId=org.dd4t -DarchetypeArtifactId=dd4t-spring-mvc-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=1.5  -DarchetypeCatalog=remote -DarchetypeCatalog=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
```

Only if you want to change the archetype's source, you'd need gpg locally. You can follow [SonaType's guide](http://blog.sonatype.com/2010/01/how-to-generate-pgp-signatures-with-maven/#.VupdspMrL_Q) on how to do that.

Comment: i am not using any profile  like release-central, i am just trying with command **mvn clean install -DskipTests** , and i am able to access dd4t dependency as normal maven dependency, but i am adding module **spring-mvc-archetype** provided with **dd4t2.0** source, which has plugin configuration maven-gpg-plugin, and it throws error while downloading plugin with given execution atributes.